# ClaimsIdentity.FindFirstValue returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I have this piece of code in my view:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var name = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
var email = identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

Once this worked just fine but then for some reason returns `null` for email even though the claim exists.(I checked claims property of `identity`.)

what are some possible reasons for this behavior ?how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi ( salam) mina! do you check the user is authenticated ?

Comment: I don't know what happened but it works again.Thanks for your time.